# Print lines that contain a value in a specific column shared by more than 1 entity in another col

Tags: terminal, grep

I want to extract only those values in Column 2 that are shared by at least 2 unique values in Column 2.

Using the same input (in this case 3- tab-separated columns):

```
waterline-n    below-sheath-v    14.8097 
dock-n    below-sheath-v     14.5095 
waterline-n    below-steel-n    11.0330 
picnic-n    below-steel-n    12.2277 
wavefront-n    at-part-of-variance-n    18.4888 
wavefront-n    between-part-of-variance-n    17.0656
audience-b    between-part-of-variance-n    17.6346 
game-n    between-part-of-variance-n    14.9652 
whereabouts-n    become-rediscovery-n    11.3556 
whereabouts-n    get-tee-n    10.9091
```

For the following desired output:

```
waterline-n    below-sheath-v    14.8097 
dock-n    below-sheath-v     14.5095 
waterline-n    below-steel-n    11.0330
picnic-n    below-steel-n    12.2277 
wavefront-n    between-part-of-variance-n    17.0656 
audience-b    between-part-of-variance-n    17.6346 
game-n    between-part-of-variance-n    14.9652
```

Is it possible to do this using grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the file twice with `awk` and using array.
I think this would be hard to do with `grep` only.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]++;next} a[$2]>1' file file
waterline-n    below-sheath-v    14.8097
dock-n    below-sheath-v     14.5095
waterline-n    below-steel-n    11.0330
picnic-n    below-steel-n    12.2277
wavefront-n    between-part-of-variance-n    17.0656
audience-b    between-part-of-variance-n    17.6346
game-n    between-part-of-variance-n    14.9652
```

In first pass `FNR==NR` it adds all the value of column 2 in an array, and increment it for every hits that passes.
In pass two it looks in the array and see if hits is more than one and if ok, print the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired output with `grep` and `uniq`. Note that there should be no correspondence between the second column and other columns. Also note that the identical fields need to be on consecutive lines unless you sort the output of `cut`:

```
grep -f <(cut -f2 infile | uniq -d) infile
```

Output:

```
waterline-n below-sheath-v  14.8097
dock-n  below-sheath-v  14.5095
waterline-n below-steel-n   11.0330
picnic-n    below-steel-n   12.2277
wavefront-n between-part-of-variance-n  17.0656
audience-b  between-part-of-variance-n  17.6346
game-n  between-part-of-variance-n  14.9652
```