# Counting specific column that correspond to a variable in other column

Tags: awk, terminal, grep

I need to count the number of times that a value in a specific column occur given a variable.

Specifically, I have a 3-column tab separated file, where I am interested to know the amount of different variables in Column 4 that a string in Column 2 occurs with.

This is an example of the input:

```
waterline-n    below-sheath-v    14.8097    A
dock-n    below-sheath-v     14.5095    B
waterline-n    below-steel-n    11.0330    A
picnic-n    below-steel-n    12.2277    C
game-n    below-steel-n    12.2277    D
dock-n    below-steel-n    12.2277    D
wavefront-n    at-part-of-variance-n    18.4888    L
wavefront-n    between-part-of-variance-n    17.0656    A
audience-b    between-part-of-variance-n    17.6346    B
game-n    between-part-of-variance-n    14.9652    C
whereabouts-n    become-rediscovery-n    11.3556    L
whereabouts-n    get-tee-n    10.9091    L
```

This is an example of the desired output:

```
waterline-n    below-sheath-v    14.8097    A   2
dock-n    below-sheath-v     14.5095    B   2
waterline-n    below-steel-n    11.0330    A    3
picnic-n    below-steel-n    12.2277    C   3
game-n    below-steel-n    12.2277    D 3
dock-n    below-steel-n    12.2277    D 3
wavefront-n    at-part-of-variance-n    18.4888    L    1
wavefront-n    between-part-of-variance-n    17.0656    A   2
audience-b    between-part-of-variance-n    17.6346    B    2
game-n    between-part-of-variance-n    14.9652    C    1
whereabouts-n    become-rediscovery-n    11.3556    L   1
whereabouts-n    get-tee-n    10.9091    L  1
```

I have tried the following awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next}{print $0 "\t" a[$2]}' file file
```

but it counts the amount of times that a unique string in Column 2 occurs in general -- whereas I need to know the number of different variables from Column 4 that it occurs with.

Is it possible to use awk or a grep to arrive at my desired results?
The file is quite large >1million lines, so optimization is important.

Comment: This is some duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705930/print-lines-that-contain-a-value-in-a-specific-column-shared-by-more-than-1-enti/19706333#19706333

Comment: No it is not. Same data, different problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a more specific array key.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2,$4]++; next} {print $0 "\t" a[$2,$4]}' file file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
awk -f count.awk input.txt
```

where `count.awk` is:

```
{
    line[NR]=$0
    if (! ($2,$4) in a) {
      a[$2,$4]++
      aa[$2]++
    }
    b[NR]=$2
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
       print line[i], aa[b[i]]
    }
}
```